# Lemma about a prime times a unit

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers

I came across this Lemma:

"Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $a,u\in R$ such that $u$ is invertible. Then $a$ is a prime if and only if $au$ is a prime.

I tried to prove it unsuccessfully, but would appreciate your help with a formal proof.

thanks :)

Comment: Units divide everything. So $a \mid c \iff (au)\mid c$.

Comment: $(a)=(au)$ are equal ideals, hence $xy\in(au)\implies x=auk\text{ or }y=auk$ iff $xy\in(a)\implies x=aj\text{ or }y=aj$.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the definitions and make use of the multiplicative inverse. Try to completely justify the following line of thought.

$a$ prime $\implies$ $au$ prime:

Let $au|xy$, and we aim to show $au$ divides $x$ or $y$. Then $a|xy$, so $a$ divides $x$ or $y$. If $az=x$, then $au(u^{-1}z)=x$ implies $au|x$. A similar statement holds if $a$ divides $y$.

$au$ prime $\implies$ $a$ prime:

Actually, this is already done! Invoke the previous argument using the prime $au$ and the prime-times-a-unit $(au)u^{-1}=a$.

Comment: in the second part of the proof, can I write $au|x$ so $auz=x$ which means $a(uz)=x$ so $a|x$?

Comment: @user114138 If you are repeating the argument in the first half for the second half, yes, I think you are doing a relevant step. But if you have a bit of time to ponder it, you should eventually realize that the "second half" was already proven by the first half. In the second half, $au$ is a prime, and $u^{-1}$ is a unit, and you are showing their product (which reduces to $a$) is prime too.