# Show that $a$ is irreducible iff $au$ is irreducible where $u$ is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> $R$ is integral domain. Show that $a$ is irreducible iff $au$ is irreducible where $u\in R^*$.

**My Try:**
Lets assume $a$ is irreducible and $au = bc \implies a=bcu^{-1}$.
We know that $u\in R^*$ so we can conclude $au$ is irreducible?

I think something is wrong. I didn't use the fact that $a$ is irreducible.

The definition of irreducibility: $q=xy \implies x\in R^* \lor y\in R^*$

Can you help me?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1019329/29335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, assume $au = bc$, then indeed $a = bcu^{-1} = b(cu^{-1})$. Then either $b \in R^\ast$ or $cu^{-1} \in R^\ast$, as $a$ is irreducible. We are done when the former is the case, so suppose $cu^{-1} \in R^\ast$, then also $(cu^{-1})u = c \in R^\ast$, as $R^\ast$ is closed under multiplication. So then $c \in R^\ast$ and you are done.

Comment: Can you explain why $R^*$ is closed under multipication please?

Comment: If $u,v$ both have inverses then $uv$ has too: $(uv)^{-1} = v^{-1}u^{-1}$, which is easy to verify.